# How to pass data between React component to a div inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a switch button component that is exported to another component (audience manager) inside the audience manager component I am returning the switch component and a div component that says OFF. How do I change the text of the div to ON when the switch component toggles/changes its state.

```js
type Props = {
   children: any;
   color?: string;
 };
 const Switch = (props:Props) => {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(false)
  
  let SwitchClass = ''
  if(props.color === 'primary') SwitchClass = ' switch-primary'
  if(props.color === 'success') SwitchClass = ' switch-success'
  if(props.color === 'info') SwitchClass = ' switch-info'

  return (
    <div className={'switch-box ' + (change ? SwitchClass : '')} onClick={() => {
      setChange(!change)
    }} >
      <div className={'switch-inner-box' + (change ? ' switch-inner-box-move': '')}> </div>
    </div>
  );
  
};

export default Switch
```

```html
 const AudienceManage = (props:Props) => {
 const [change, setChange] = useState(false)

 function doSomething () {
  let x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  if (x.innerHTML === "OFF") {
   x.innerHTML = "ON";
  } else {
   x.innerHTML = "OFF";
 }
}

 return (
   <PageContainer>
     <h1>
       AudienceManage 
     </h1>   
         
     <div id='myDiv'>OFF</div>
        <Switch  onClick={doSomething} color='primary'/> <br/>
   
   </PageContainer>
 );
};

export default AudienceManage;
```

Comment: can you put your code on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at my sample, replicating your desire behavior. Basically you pass a function from parent component to the `<Switch />` component.

Within this `<Switch />` component, you call this passed prop to update in the parent scope.

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Switch = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const onClickHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setState(!state);
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(state);
  }, [state]);

  return <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Switch {state.toString()}</button>;
};

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
  const onSwitchClicked = useCallback(switchState => {
    console.log("switch: ", switchState);
    setValue(switchState);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Switch state: {value.toString()}</h1>
      <Switch onChange={onSwitchClicked} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hugle-29nwb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Hope this help,

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things gone wrong in your code. In this example AudienceManage should keep the state and change handler of your toggle component and pass both of them through props. The Switch component can be stateless and use the prop to display it's state and the handler prop to change the state in the parent component. This state change will trigger a re-render and your Switch component will reflect the correct state.

This link could be helpful:
[Lifting State Up - React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)